# A quiet man with quiet ways

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, vocabulary

could you, please, help me to understand what kind of person is "a quiet man with quiet ways"?

May it be, that this man is quiet and self-collected?

Here is the context:

"A quiet man with quiet ways, he unfolded himself from the chair
to go sit by his mother-in-law. She patted his hand."
N.Roberts

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. It would mean an unassuming person who keeps to themselves and goes about their life without making a fuss.